# How to return back with error/success message in laravel blade view?

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-blade

The URL that sends the request is:

> http://localhost:8000/my_details?my_id='.$id

My Controller looks like this:

```
public function my_action(Request $request){
    $myauth=$request->validate([
        'remarks' => 'required'
    ]);
    $full_name = Auth::user()->full_name;
    $id=$request->input('id');
    $user_remarks=$request->input('user_remarks');
    $remarks=$myauth['remarks'];
    $status=$request->input('status');
    $newremarks=$user_remarks . ' ' . $full_name . ': ' . $remarks .';';
    $result=DB::table('my_record')->where('id',$id)->update([
        'remarks'=>$newremarks,
        'status'=>$status,
    ]);
    if($result){
        return redirect(route('my_details?my_id='.$id))->with('success', 'Action taken successfully.');
    }
    return redirect(route('my_details?my_id='.$id))->with('error','Remarks cannot be empty');
}
```

My Blade looks like:

```
<div>
    @if(Session::has('error'))
        <div class="w3-panel w3-red" role="alert">
            {{ Session::get('error') }}
        </div>
    @endif
    @if(Session::has('success'))
        <div class="w3-panel w3-green" role="alert">
            {{ Session::get('success') }}
        </div>
    @endif
</div>
```

I want the controller to send the success message or error message on the same blade view that sends the request.

Answer (score 1):

So if you want to a to return back to a previous route with a fail/success message, you need to use redirect with payload.

**Route examples:**

For redirection:

```
return redirect()->route('Communities.Index');
```

For redirection to previous route: `return redirect()->back();`

For redirection with payload:

```
return redirect()->route('Communities.Index')->with('success', 'Item added to cart successfully!');

return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'This is an error message.');
```

Comment: This worked for successful entry but if the input validation fails it doesn't show any error.

Comment: in the previous route(my_details), you need to handle the error as well

Comment: I'm still confused how do you handle the error. I'm sending the data from a form input from the URL and validating the value in the controller and returning the same URL.

Comment: you are correct, but the method in controller which returns the form (my_details i am assuming, here you need to handle it). can you show me the controller code, which returns the blade file containing the form?

Comment: Its given in the question itself that's the only controller I have at the moment.

Comment: can you share the web.php (routes) file?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function my_action(Request $request){
    $myauth=$request->validate([
        'remarks' => 'required'
    ]);
    $full_name = Auth::user()->full_name;
    $id=$request->input('id');
    $user_remarks=$request->input('user_remarks');
    $remarks=$myauth['remarks'];
    $status=$request->input('status');
    $newremarks=$user_remarks . ' ' . $full_name . ': ' . $remarks .';';
    $result=DB::table('my_record')->where('id',$id)->update([
        'remarks'=>$newremarks,
        'status'=>$status,
    ]);
    if($result){
        return redirect()->route('my_details',$id)->with('success', 'Action taken successfully.');
    }
    return redirect()->route('my_details',$id)->with('error','Remarks cannot be empty');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

#### In controller it should be

```
public function my_action(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'remarks' => 'required'
    ]);
    
    $full_name = Auth::user()->full_name;
    $id=$request->input('id');
    $user_remarks=$request->input('user_remarks');
    $remarks=$myauth['remarks'];
    $status=$request->input('status');
    $newremarks=$user_remarks . ' ' . $full_name . ': ' . $remarks .';';
    $result=DB::table('my_record')->where('id',$id)->update([
        'remarks'=>$newremarks,
        'status'=>$status,
    ]);
    if($result){
        return redirect(route('my_details?my_id='.$id))->with('success', 'Action taken successfully.');
    }
    return redirect(route('my_details?my_id='.$id))->with('error','Remarks cannot be empty');
}
```

#### in blade it should be like below to show error underneath of each input

```
<input type="text" name="remarks">
@if($errors->has('remarks'))
    <div class="error">{{ $errors->first('remarks') }}</div>
@endif
```

#### show all errors in loop

```
@if($errors->any())
    {{ implode('', $errors->all('<div>:message</div>')) }}
@endif
```

#### Alternatively You may use laravel Validator class as well to validate

this way you can handle ajax response too

```
 $validator = Validator::make($requst->all(),
       'remarks' => 'required'
 );

 if ($validator->fails())
 {
        return redirect(route('my_details?my_id='.$id))->withErrors($validator);
 }
```